# Android Listview can't be set for textview

Tags: android, listview

am trying to set `ListView` for this text view using ListView Adapter but making Error:

```
(25, 29) error: no suitable constructor found for
                       ArrayAdapter(MainActivity,int,int,String)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(
                       Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,
                       List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to List<String>)
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    // Fetch emails from contact list
    String emailStr = refreshData();
    // Show emails on screen
    output.setText(emailStr);
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,R.id.output,emailStr));

}


private String refreshData() {
    String emaildata = "";

    try {

        /**************************************************/

        ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext()
                .getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr
                .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

            Log.i("Content provider", "Reading contact  emails");

            while (cur
                    .moveToNext()) {

                String contactId = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                // Create query to use CommonDataKinds classes to fetch emails
                Cursor emails = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = " + contactId, null, null);

                        /*
                        //You can use all columns defined for ContactsContract.Data
                        // Query to get phone numbers by directly call data table column

                        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                  new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
                                  Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                                          + Data.MIMETYPE + "= + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + ",
                                  new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
                        */

                while (emails.moveToNext()) {

                    // This would allow you get several email addresses
                    String emailAddress = emails
                            .getString(emails
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                    //Log.e("email==>", emailAddress);

                    emaildata +=" "+emailAddress+" ";
                }

                emails.close();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            emaildata +=" Data not found. ";

        }
        cur.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {

        emaildata +=" Exception : "+e+" ";
    }

    return emaildata;
}

}
```

Comment: you need to collect `emailAddress` in a list and pass to adpater as a fourth parameter while creating adapter

Comment: `emailStr` is a String where it should be an `Array` when you want to pass it to the `ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` adapter take Array not string object:

```
 output.setText(emailStr);
```

`emailStr` is string here Its should be Array.check syntax here

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.activity_main,R.id.output,arr[]));
```

Comment: private String refreshData()  his method only sending back only one string how you can set it as adapter array.. first he need to send the array back from his method

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list =  refreshData();
```

and make sure your your function returns ArrayList

```
    private ArrayList<String> refreshData() {
String emaildata = "";
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

try {

    /**************************************************/

    ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext()
            .getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

        Log.i("Content provider", "Reading contact  emails");

        while (cur
                .moveToNext()) {

            String contactId = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            // Create query to use CommonDataKinds classes to fetch emails
            Cursor emails = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = " + contactId, null, null);

                    /*
                    //You can use all columns defined for ContactsContract.Data
                    // Query to get phone numbers by directly call data table column

                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                              new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
                              Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                                      + Data.MIMETYPE + "= + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + ",
                              new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
                    */

            while (emails.moveToNext()) {


                String emailAddress = emails
                        .getString(emails  .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                emaildata +=" "+emailAddress+" ";
     list.add(emaildata);
            }

            emails.close();
        }

    }

    cur.close();


} catch (Exception e) {
}

return list;
}
```

and finally set it to your adapter

```
  this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,R.id.output,list));
```

and you can check the size to know whether that contact has emails or not by

```
  int count = list.size();
 if (count > 0) it has values else not
```

I am not sure Are you getting correct values if you retrieving correct values it should work...

Comment: Error:(28, 28) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>
Error:(102, 16) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to String

Comment: will using text am getting values but cant use list view

Comment: have you checked with my method which is above posted you should return list  whichs type is ArrayList<String>

Comment: error is return list ..tat make refresh data java.util.arraylist<java.lang.String>

Comment: check your refreshData() method thats what am talking

Comment: Sorry my mistake.... change your methods Return type as ArrayList<String> then everything will be fine

Comment: private ArryaList<String> refreshData() {} will do the workg

Comment: hey i have a doubt i want to create listview in xml or not where  the id should mention

Comment: after changing ArryaList<String>  what have you got??

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: post your Layout file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ListView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      
      
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: your layout file should a ListView and which one's id should be like this      android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: You have to learn a lot just Read the Documentation Completely https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html  this is documentation about ListActivity

Comment: i even used different cursor query its not showing in listview